# How to create a quick python GUI for controlling webcam input to be used for the purpose of facial detection?

Tags: python, user-interface, webcam, dlib

I am trying to build a python application involving facial detection in real time using webcam with the help of dlib library. I wish to create a simple python GUI for controlling the webcam stream. I tried to search for Tkinter or PyQt GUIs but could not find one. Please suggest me some code snippet or site where I can find one.

Comment: Are you looking for something specific? Because a simple search for Tkinter examples should spit out several code snippets and examlpes. You might for example look on Github [link](https://github.com/Dvlv/Tkinter-By-Example)

Comment: The book is no doubt very resourceful Bernhard but more specifically I wanted an interface with buttons to control start and stop of a webcam. Please suggest a suitable place to find the same. Thank you @Bernhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was searching on Youtube I came across this video which has exactly what I wanted viz. a simple GUI for controlling webcam using **PyQt5**. The link is as follows:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUpC6z32bCA

Hope this will be helpful for all those having the same query.